# conda stuck on Proceed ([y]/n)? when updating packages in ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder, graphlab

I just downloaded Anaconda 4.2.0 (with python 3.5.2) for Mac OS X. Whenever I try to update any packages etc, my ipython console presents the package dependencies and displays "Proceed ([y]/n)?" but does not take any inputs. E.g. I press enter, or y-enter etc. and nothing happens. Here's an example:

```
!conda create -n graphlab-env python=2.7 anaconda
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /Users/Abhijit/anaconda/envs/graphlab-env:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    python-2.7.12              |                1         9.5 MB
    _license-1.1               |           py27_1          80 KB
    alabaster-0.7.9            |           py27_0          11 KB
    anaconda-clean-1.0.0       |           py27_0           3 KB
.
.
.
    nbpresent-3.0.2            |           py27_0         463 KB
    anaconda-4.2.0             |      np111py27_0           6 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       143.9 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _license:           1.1-py27_1         
    _nb_ext_conf:       0.3.0-py27_0       
    alabaster:          0.7.9-py27_0       
    anaconda:           4.2.0-np111py27_0  
    anaconda-clean:     1.0.0-py27_0       
.
.
.
    yaml:               0.1.6-0            
    zlib:               1.2.8-3            

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

It won't respond after this step. When I enter 'Ctrl-C' it breaks out of this loop. I have tried Shift-Enter, Alt-Enter, Ctrl-Enter, Cmd-Enter etc but no luck. Tearing my hair out over this. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check your internet connection, or may be the package you are trying to download is not available right now.

Comment: Internet connection is fine. This happens with every update where it displays the 'Proceed?' part. For a single package update where the Proceed? part is not shown i.e. when it does not need any input, it works without any problems. I have updated and re-installed Anaconda multiple times and this has not solved the issue.

Comment: Just started running into this issue with a fresh install of Anaconda. Moreover, it *really* hangs on `conda install jupyter` even when passing `-y`

Answer (score 72):

You can launch shell commands with the `!` operator in ipython, but you can't interact with them after the process has launched.

Therefore, you could:

1. execute your conda command outside of your ipython session (IOW, a normal shell); or
2. pass the `--yes` flag. e.g.:

`!conda create -n graphlab-env python=2.7 anaconda -y`

Answer (score 44):

Add `--yes` at the end of the command.

For example:

```
%conda install --yes seaborn
```

Comment: fyi `pip uninstall pipupgrade --yes` also works for pip users

Answer (score 10):

Solution:

```
!conda update --update-all --yes
```

or shortly:

```
!conda update --all -y
```

Answer (score 8):

Just Append -y to any command to say yes to all the yes/no questions. Most of the packages are configured in a way to work with this.
For your:

```
!conda create -n graphlab-env python=2.7 anaconda -y
```