# Easy install python modules for Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Lately I've been learning a bit about Python. Jupyter notebooks seem like a good idea in theory, in practice I'm having some difficulty setting up the python modules within a Jupyter environment.

For example, I found this neat [geographical data article](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-data-at-the-zip-code-level-with-folium-d07ac983db20) and I want to follow along. There is a very nice [github project](https://github.com/finnqiao/la_restaurant_inspection) that I downloaded to follow along.

Start up Jupyter and everything looks in order until I run the first code block:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import missingno as msno
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
```

This immediately generates an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-422e89229f53> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import re
      3 from datetime import datetime
      4 from dateutil.parser import parse
      5 import missingno as msno

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

There are quite a few modules and I guess I can go into the command line to add them each individually. That doesn't seem efficient. Is there some other 'Jupyter' or 'Conda' way to do this?

Comment: ideally, a project will provide a requirements.txt file. but in this case, i would use `conda install` to get the required libraries

Comment: also, you can pass as many libraries to a single `conda install` command as you like

Comment: @PaulH I made another question for my follow up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64489517/what-to-do-when-conda-cant-find-a-python-package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Jupyter notebooks you can execute command line methods using `!` at the start of the line e.g.

`! conda install pandas --yes`

More detail on the inner working is discussed in this question:
[Running interactive command line code from Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44604027/6709902)

Thanks to @PaulH for pointing out the need to add the `--yes` flag.

Comment: you're going to want to add a `--yes` flag...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826250/conda-stuck-on-proceed-y-n-when-updating-packages-in-ipython-console/39841757#39841757

Answer (score 0):

just run this in Jupyter:

```
!pip install <the name of the module>, <the name of the module>, <the name of the module>...
```

this will install the module you choose.
For example :

```
!pip install pandas, re, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure that I added "python -m" so my final code was "!python -m pip install module_name"

if you want to add multiple modules at once you just add them with spaces in between. (no commas as another answer put, but I can't comment due to little points on my account)

multiple modules at once => "!python -m pip install module_name1 module_name2 ..."