# What to do when Conda can't find a Python package?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm pretty new to Python and a Jupyter Notebook Novice. I'm trying to follow along with an excellent tutorial about [LA Maps](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-data-at-the-zip-code-level-with-folium-d07ac983db20). The author even included the [Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/finnqiao/la_restaurant_inspection) on Github. I download the notebook and fire up Jupyter to get to work. Only I can't seem to figure out how to install the required packages. Pandas seems to install fine but I can't install 're':

```
(admininstall) C:\>conda install re
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - re

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I did search for 're' at https://anaconda.org but didn't find 're', there was an 're2'. I'm not sure if that is what is needed. What is my next step?

Comment: `re` is a built-in module. in other words, it comes with every installation of python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re` is part of the Python standard packages, so no need to install it as it comes with almost every Python distribution.

However, to answer your question, you can search for the package on the Anaconda repository at https://anaconda.org.  If it is in a non-default channel (the Anaconda channel is the default), you can install it by adding the channel as an argument.

The `jellyfish` package is a good example.  It is posted on several other channels, but not the main one.  To install it from the conda-forge channel, use:

```
conda install jellyfish -c conda-forge
```

If the package is not available as a conda package, you might be able to find it as a PIP installable package on https://pypi.org/.  The `pypac` package is an example of this.  To install it from PyPi use:

```
pip install pypac
```